# Add files to the upload table individually and upload all of them at once (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I want to create a custom upload table where, when i press add files it allows me to select one or more files and populates its info in the upload table like size,name,type. At the bottom it should show total size of the file on the table, and when i click upload button it should upload all the files on the table which i process later using AJAX... Any Help would be very much appreciated.

Sample Table:
[image]

## EDIT:

i am unable to get the total no. of files being selected. If i get total no of files selected how to get respective properties as name,type,size

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table id="myfiles" border="1px solid" cellpadding="1px" align="center" width="80%">
    <tr>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" align="left">
        Total upload size: <span id="totalsize"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
           <input type="file" id="addfiles" name="myfiles[]" multiple> 
        </th>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>

javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
  addfiles.onchange = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('addfiles');
    var tabl = document.getElementById('myfiles');
    var totsize = 0;

    //total no of files selected
    no_of_files_selected = a.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < (no_of_files_selected); i++){
      var b = tabl.insertRow(-1);
      b.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "filename here";
      b.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "size of file here";
      totsize = totsize  + "size of individual file";
    }

   document.getElementById("totalsize").innerHTML = totsize + 'MB';

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Provide some code so far you did.

Comment: Here's a plugin for file upload: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/  You can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks man, but i was thinking of making it in pure javascript @AkhileshBChandran